# Forwarding an RTSP stream from IP camera to youtube

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtsp

I have an IP camera (Foscam FI9800P) capable of sending an RTSP stream (I've confirmed using VLC the stream works). I want to stream the video from that camera to youtube.

I'm guessing the camera can't send it to youtube directly, so I need a device in the middle. Something like:

IP Camera --> Raspberry Pi --> Youtube live

Ideally I'd like to do this without re-encoding the video along the way.  ffmpeg appears to be able to do this, but it has many options and I haven't been able to figure out all its command line options.

Any suggestions to how I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

Restreamer should be able to create the setup that you are looking for https://datarhei.github.io/restreamer

It uses NGINX and FFmpeg under the hood and has a user friendly web frontend to configure the stream.

Answer (score -3):

Please check the link below,
in this guide, you will be using "ffmpeg"
this guide is very clear and has photos also,
in this guide, they use their computer as a streaming server,
you also can do it on a raspberry pi

"IP CAMERA RTSP STREAM TO YOUTUBE LIVE"
https://www.unifore.net/ip-video-surveillance/yoosee-wi-fi-camera-rtsp-stream-to-youtube-live.html

if you have any problem you can ask me.

Comment: that's not a good kind of answer: An answer should stand on its own to some degree. Summarize the link's content, please!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.